# Equation sub-numbering

Tags: equations, numbering

How can I label my equations as:

```
a = b+c (1(a))
d = f+g (1(b))
```

Please advice as I have used simple labeling structure `\label` but don't know how to handle the letters.

Answer (score 21):

You can use the `subequations` environment from [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
y & = d \\
y & = cx + d \\
y & = bx ^{2}+ cx + d \\
y & = ax ^{3}+ bx ^{2}+ cx + d
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo for your prompt reply. What if I can't write my subequation under one \begin {subequation} and \end{subequation}? Actually my two equations have text in between, mean 1(a) then some text then 1(b). I hope i am making clear here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user47254 For short texts you can use `\intertext{text text...}`.